# Populating datagrid by changing data available in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am trying to populate a datagridview from a datatable having data retrieved from database.

While populating the columns and rows, I want the data to be formatted available in column of datatable. I dont want the data to be changed in datatable before populating, however I want the data to be changed while binding to grid. Please help me if this can done using any grid properties.

Ex : Want to populate column with data "YES" instead "Y" available in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try RowDataBound

```
protected void GridViewProducts_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row .RowType == DataControlRowType .DataRow )
        {
           e.Row.Cells[2].Text = (e.Row.Cells[2].Text=="Y" ? "YES" : "NO"); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `RowDataBound` event handler:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "Y" ? "Yes" : "No"); 
}
```

**OR**

You can copy your original `DataTable` using `Copy` method:

```
DataTable copyDataTable = dataTable.Copy();
```

**Using `Loops`:**

```
foreach (DataRow dr in copyDataTable.Rows)
{
    dr["columnName"] = dr["columnName"].ToString().Equals("Y") ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

**Using `Linq`:**

```
copyDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c["columnName"].ToString().Equals("Y"))
         .ToList().ForEach(c => c["columnName"] = "Yes");
copyDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c["columnName"].ToString().Equals("N"))
         .ToList().ForEach(c => c["columnName"] = "No");
```